# Change color of 3D object in Android using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, colors, opengl-es-2.0

I have loaded a 3D object in android app using OpenGL ES 2.0. as [demo of OpenGL ES 2.0](https://github.com/andresoviedo/android-3D-model-viewer)

Now I need to change that loaded object color at runtime when a button is clicked.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad.

For the start, there's no such thing as a "color of 3D object in OpenglES 2.0". Any "color" is a part of rendering pipeline used in exact app, it's either a property of a shader, or argument to shader, used in one or more rendering steps to get the final visuals of a groups of polygons. So we can't know what steps are required to change appearance of polygons being rendered within your app.

The next broad thing is 3D models loaded. There are tons of formats, each having different capabilities. The single model might be represented in multiple sub-meshes with different materials, involving different shaders and even vertex formats. That example you're referencing can load "Wavefront OBJ" and "Collada" formats. That's probably an extremes of the range of possible 3D model formats. Collada can produce a huge variety of vertex formats and material attributes applied to geometry, so there's simply no direct answer on "how to change the color of an object".

There might be simple changes to the example you've used, to make all polys to be rendered in the same shade, but that would require a significant work on materials you have, and that's beyond the format of "question-answer" discussion.